# HighCharts gauge know the displayed numericSymbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

In highcharts numeric symbols are `'k'` , `'m'` , ... wehre `'k'` stands for `thousand '000'` and `'m'` stands for `million` ...
How can i know what will be the displayed `numericSymbol` `'k'` or `'m'` or ..
I want to display a ratio where instead of `'k' '1000' or 'm' '1000000'` or ...
Note sometimes gauge displays 1000, 2000, ... instead of 1k,2k, ...
For this reason i want to know the `numericSymbol` that gauge chart will display in order to know which ratio to add

Comment: Try the label.formatter

Comment: how to try i!! suppose i want to read the data after creating the chart is that possible !! the same question reading numericSymbol after chart creation

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want to know if given certain data, will it show numeric symbol?  Or after the plot is drawn, did it show numeric symbol?  For the former consult the source code, line 6592 the `defaultLabelFormatter` function.  For the later, `Highcharts.charts[0].yAxis[0].ticks[0].label.textStr`